# probability density function from monte carlo simulation

Tags: r, excel, matplotlib, statistics, probability-density

I have a proprietary software that generates some data and plots probability density function. I am trying to reproduce it with python. However, plots don't match up.
My code is below.
Over here, I tested it with just 30 points, but the software allows to generate as many as I want.

[coding ground](http://tpcg.io/_X3M61I)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x=[1.97e-08, 1.41e-08, 1.71e-09, 8.43e-10, 4.31e-08, 5.95e-08, 3.15e-09, 3.2e-08, 7.46e-10, 4.67e-08, 4.44e-08, 3.01e-09, 8.27e-09, 4.39e-09, 2.4e-09, 3.11e-08, 7.8e-11, 8.58e-07, 2.31e-08, 5.9e-09, 3.41e-08, 2.64e-08, 2.52e-08, 3.63e-08, 2.43e-09, 3.09e-07, 4.42e-09, 8.84e-09, 1.21e-07, 3.6e-10]

num_bins = 9000000
#y,x
hist, edges = np.histogram(
    x,
    bins=num_bins,
    density=True)
print(hist)
print(edges)

xx=edges
yy=hist
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( xx[:-1], yy )
# ax.set_xlim(1E-12, 1E-5)
# ax.set_ylim(0, 0.4E+7)
ax.set(xscale="log")
#ax.set(yscale="log")
plt.xlim(min(edges), max(edges))
plt.ylim(min(hist), max(hist))
plt.show()
```

[image]

But the software that generated this data also plotted this:
[image]